# No puedo insertar datos a mi base de datos SQLite usando Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy intentando resolver un ejercicio de crear una aplicacion en la que se pueda ingresar el RUT de una persona, el nombre y 3 notas a una base de datos SQLite, pero me esta fallando a insercion de datos y no puedo identificar el problema.

Ya cree anteriormente una aplicacion en la que se ingresa el RUT, Nombre y edad de una persona, en la que no tuve ningun problema ingresado los datos a la base de datos, de ese codigo hice esta nueva aplicacion solo cambiando las columnas de la tabla, el nombre de la base de datos, el nombre de la tabla y los datos ingresados.

Activity de insertar

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InsertarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edtRut, edtNombre, edtNota1, edtNota2, edtNota3;
    private Button btnInsertar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insertar);
        edtRut=findViewById(R.id.edt_rut);
        edtNombre=findViewById(R.id.edt_nom);
        edtNota1=findViewById(R.id.edt_n1);
        edtNota2=findViewById(R.id.edt_n2);
        edtNota3=findViewById(R.id.edt_n3);
        btnInsertar=findViewById(R.id.btn_insertar);
        btnInsertar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String rut,nombre;
                int nota1,nota2,nota3;
                rut=edtRut.getText().toString();
                nombre=edtNombre.getText().toString();
                nota1 = Integer.parseInt(edtNota1.getText().toString());
                nota2 = Integer.parseInt(edtNota2.getText().toString());
                nota3 = Integer.parseInt(edtNota3.getText().toString());
                CrearBD creaBd=new CrearBD(InsertarActivity.this,"bd_nota3", null,1);
                SQLiteDatabase db=creaBd.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues registro=new ContentValues();
                registro.put("rut",rut);
                registro.put("nombre",nombre);
                registro.put("Nota 1",nota1);
                registro.put("Nota 2",nota2);
                registro.put("Nota 3",nota3);
                long valor = db.insert("tabla_alumno",null,registro);
                if (valor>0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertarActivity.this, "Registro Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edtRut.requestFocus();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(InsertarActivity.this, "Registro No Insertado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Clase de base de datos

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CrearBD extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public CrearBD(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table tabla_alumno(rut text primary key, nombre text not null, nota1 integer not null, nota2 integer not null, nota3 integer not null)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("drop table tabla_alumno");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el problema sea que está intentando guardar notas (tipo float) como enteros (int) cuando las convierte desde los EditText con Integer.parseInt(). En lugar de eso, debería usar Float.parseFloat().

Por ejemplo, en lugar de esto:

```
nota1 = Integer.parseInt(edtNota1.getText().toString());
```

Debería hacer esto:

```
nota1 = Float.parseFloat(edtNota1.getText().toString());
```

También debería asegurarse de que los valores en los EditText sean válidos para convertir a float, y manejar cualquier excepción que se produzca de manera adecuada. Por ejemplo, si un usuario ingresa un valor que no puede convertirse a float, su código generará una excepción de tipo *NumberFormatException*. Puede controlar esa excepción y manejarla de manera adecuada, como mostrando un mensaje de error al usuario.

Espero que esto ayude. Si tiene más preguntas o necesita más ayuda, no dude en preguntar.

Comment: Intente hacer el cambio a `Float.parseFloat` pero me daba error `Incompatible types. Found: 'float', required: 'int'`  por lo que en vez de definir a las notas como `Float` las puse como `int`, pero esto no me resolvio el problema.

Comment: Puedes editar tu post con el nuevo código y también adjuntar el código de error completo por favor

Comment: Ahi esta el codigo editado, y el codigo que envie anteriormente es el codigo de error completo.

Comment: Pude resolver mi problema y ahora puedo ingresar datos a mi tabla, la verdad no se cual fue el problema ya que hice un proyecto nuevo desde cero siguendo los mismos pasos y esta vez funciono, pero se agradece la ayuda de todas formas!